# SSLServerHasCertificateAuthority is false but the certificate is signed by a trusted CA

Tags: mongodb, ssl, certificate

I am enabling TLS/SSL encryption on a remote MongoDB instance (running on Windows Server 2012 R2). On the instance's server, `devserver.external`, I have created an SSL certificate. The CN on the subject is `devserver.external` and the issuer is `company-issuer`. On my computer (the one with which I am connecting to the remote mongo instance, Windows 10) I have `company-issuer` in my Intermediate Certification Authorities (when viewed through the Windows certificate manager). This is an internal company operated CA that is trusted on all company machines, including the dev server and my machine.

When connecting to mongo, via either `mongo` on the command line or the Robo3t client, the connection succeeds over SSL but `db.serverStatus().security.SSLServerHasCertificateAuthority` is `false`. From the [mongo docs](http://www.dba86.com/docs/mongo/3.0/reference/command/serverStatus.html#security):

> A boolean that is true when the TLS/SSL certificate specified by net.ssl.PEMKeyPassword is associated with a certificate authority. **false when the TLS/SSL certificate is self-signed.**

So it would seem mongo is interpreting my CA-signed certificate as a self-signed certificate. This is obviously unwanted behaviour.

My `mongod.cfg` is:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: E:\MongoData\Log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: e:\MongoData\DB
setParameter:
    enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
security:
    authorization: enabled
net:
    ssl:
        mode: requireSSL
        PEMKeyFile: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\mongodb2.pem
```

My `mongodb2.pem` is:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<base64 encoded private key>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<base64 encoded certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I've not included a CA file because as stated in the [configuration reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.CAFile):

> Changed in version 3.4: If --sslCAFile is not specified when connecting to an TLS/SSL-enabled server, the system-wide CA certificate store will be used.

My interpretation of this is: As I have not included a `net.ssl.CAFile` in my `mongod.cfg`, my mongo server will look to the Windows certificate store for a list of trusted CAs. In which it would find my `company-issuer` CA, which is the issuer for the certificate in `mongodb2.pem`.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you MongoDB version?

Comment: How you are connecting the "mongo" shell with ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

As MongoDB BOL documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/) to connect to a [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) or [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/#bin.mongos) instance that requires [encrypted communication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#ssl-mongod-ssl-cert-key), start [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell with [--ssl](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-ssl) and include the [--sslCAFile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-sslcafile) to validate the server certificates.

```
mongo --ssl --host hostname.example.com --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```

For example, given an TLS/SSL certificate located at /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem, configure mongod to use TLS/SSL encryption for all connections with the following command:

```
mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem <additional options>
```

**Set Up mongod and mongos with Certificate Validation**

To set up mongod or mongos for TLS/SSL encryption using an TLS/SSL certificate signed by a certificate authority, include the following run-time options during startup:

- [**`net.ssl.mode`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.mode) set to `requireSSL`. This setting restricts each server to
  use only TLS/SSL encrypted connections. You can also specify either
  the value allowSSL or preferSSL to set up the use of mixed TLS/SSL
  modes on a port. See net.ssl.mode for details.
- **`PEMKeyfile`** with the    name of the `.pem` file that contains the
  signed TLS/SSL certificate    and key.
- [**`CAFile`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.CAFile) with the name of the `.pem` file that contains the root
  certificate chain from the Certificate Authority.

> **Note:**
>
> 1. Specify the  file and the  file with either the full path
>      name or the relative path name.
> 2. If the  is encrypted, specify
>          the passphrase. See TLS/SSL
>          Certificate Passphrase.

You may also specify these options in the  [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/), as in the following examples:

If using the [YAML configuration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) file format, include the following configuration in the file:

```
net:
   ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
      CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```

**Connect to MongoDB Instance that Requires Client Certificates**

To connect to a mongod or mongos that requires [CA-signed client certificates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#ssl-mongod-ca-signed-ssl-cert-key), start the mongo shell with `--ssl`, the --host option to specify the host to which to connect, the `--sslPEMKeyFile` option to specify the signed certificate-key file, and the `--sslCAFile` to validate the `server certificates`.

```
mongo --ssl --host hostname.example.com --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/client.pem --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/ca.pem
```